Doing a recursive sqlalchemy selectinload query for a many to many relationship
I have a many to many self referential relationship where data looks like:
{
  "parent": {
    "child": {
      "nodes": [
        {
          "nodes": [
            {
              "attr": "value",
              "nodes": []
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "nodes": [
            {
              "attr": "value",
              "nodes": []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

So I do a query like this:
statement = select(Parent)
  .filter(Parent.id == parent_id)
  .options(selectinload(Parent.child).
           .selectinload(Child.nodes)
           .selectinload(Child.nodes)
           .selectinload(Child.nodes)
  )
result = await async_session.execute(statement)

parent = result.scalars().first()


And that will give me 3 levels deep of nodes in my json output.  But is there a way to do that so it goes as many levels deep as needed until nodes = [] ?  Do I need to use something like marshmallow-sqlalchemy ?  Or is there an easy way to do this?
Thanks
Jon
SQLAlchemy             2.0.36
asyncpg                0.30.0
fastapi                0.112.0
Editing to add a possible workaround if there's a way to do this dynamically.
select_options=[
      selectinload(Parent.child)
      .selectinload(Node.nodes)
]
query = select(Parent)
    query = query.filter(Parent.id == parent_id)
    for option in select_options:
      query = query.options(option)

So the above allows me to dynamically add as many options to the query.  But I can't figure out how to add as many suboptions to the query. I want to chain a bunch of selectinload(). How can I do this dynamically:
.options(
  selectinload(Parent.child)
    .selectinload(Child.nodes)
    .selectinload(Child.nodes)
    .selectinload(Child.nodes)
    .selectinload(Child.nodes)
    .selectinload(Child.nodes)
    .selectinload(Child.nodes)
)

Is there a way I can create a loop to add all those .selectinload() methods? The above works great because I can see nodes that are 6 levels deep. And if I only have 3 levels deep of nodes, it works too.  So if I could just do a loop of adding 50 selectinloads, it will cover everything up to 50 levels deep which is more than enough for my purposes.

Is there anyway to get Node.nodes without using selectinload?  In my limited experience, when I have a 1 to many relationship, I can never view the "many" data.  So in above, there is not way to see node.nodes unless I use selectinload.  And the problem with that is, if I don't know the depth ahead of time, I have no idea how many selectinloads I have to do.  Is there a something that can be done in the model to not require the selectinload?

Not dynamic, but selectinload takes an argument recursion_depth, so this eliminates the need for a loop. You should be able to just do
statement = select(Parent)
  .filter(Parent.id == parent_id)
  .options(selectinload(Parent.selectinload(Child.nodes, recursion_depth=<depth>))


Are you serious?  OMG! I didn't see that in the docs at all.  I'll give that a try on Monday and see how it does.  That's awesome.  Great info.  Thanks!

Awesome solution.  This worked.

From another thread, I got this solution to do a recursive selectinload:
  child_select = selectinload(Parent.child)
  for _ in range(<depth>):
    child_select = child_select.selectinload(
      child_select.nodes)

  statement = select(Parent).filter(
    Parent.id == parent_id).options(child_select)
  result = await session.execute(statement)
  parent = result.scalars().first()

